# how to explain propose of public class in Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, comments

Hi I was asked to explain the purpose of each public class, public method, and public field in my program, but I do not know what to write it, for example is @param only for methods?

Can you give an example of each class, method and field for javadoc please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Eclipse` then type `/**` and press enter just before the method or class declaration you want to document.
For each method/class the corresponding anotations will appear and you can write the details of method/class.
By pressing `ctrl+space` inside this area you can see all the available `@` options for documentation purposes

Answer (score 3):

First [here is the oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

The standard way is:

```
/**
* This class does XYZ, here goes a description of your class
* @author Alex Jj
* @version 1.0
*/
```

The standard is:

At the top of your `.java` file, include the copyright license.

After the imports, include the class JavaDoc, this starts with a description of your lines, you may use tags like `<p>` for paragraph, `<code>` for code samples etc.

- Then you add the `@author` tags, one per author, this is usually your full name. This is required.
- After that, you have the `@version` tag, this is required
- After that, you usually have tags like `@see` (refers to other classes that are relevant)
- Followed by `@since` which is the first version of Java you are supporting

For a nice example [here is how java.lang.String is documented](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java/?v=source).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If there is a field like String name = "Myname"; is it a public parameter? sorry if the question is not related to the min subject.

Comment: Yes. If you have any more questions please open a new questions or look at the first page I linked to. If this answer solved your issue please consider accepting it .